# Disable Microsoft flow on OneDrive For Business Sites

Tags: office-365, onedrive-for-business

I am trying to disable flow on all of OD4B sites using PowerShell scripts. As per the documentation/blogs we can disable Flows by setting DisableFlows and DisableAppViews using Set-SPOSite. It's working great with SPO Sites but when I am trying the same with the personal site I am getting an error. Please let me know how to handle the same. As per error, those properties do not enable for personal sites.

```
Set-SPOSite: https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/srinivasp_tenant_onmicrosoft_com is a OneDrive for Business site collection. The only valid
parameters for this type of site collection are '-Identity', '-StorageQuota', '-StorageWarningLevel', '-LockState' and '-SharingCapability'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-SPOSite -Identity "https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/per ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-SPOSite], ServerException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SetSite
```